# Bold \hlines for longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, rules

I've searched the topic and found the following two answers.

**Answer 1.** [LaTeX tables: How do I make bold horizontal lines (typically `\hline`)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/latex-tables-how-do-i-make-bold-horizontal-lines-typically-hline)

The best answer suggests to use `booktabs`. However `booktabs` documentation says:

> A somewhat technical note: within a `longtable`, `\hline` and `\hline\hline`
>   both produce a double rule (to allow for page breaks occurring at that point).
>   But the `booktabs` rules do not. Longtable’s automatic doubling of `\hline` is
>   questionable, even according to the documentation within that package. But
>   doubled `booktabs` rules make almost no sense at all. **In the unfortunate event
>   that a `booktabs` rule should occur at a page break, then you will have to make the
>   necessary adjustments by hand.** (In general, this will mean deleting the oﬀending
>   rule.)

That's not the way it works. I don't want to make any more adjustments by hand since there are already a lot of things to be checked over.

**Answer 2.** [Longtable does not break correctly when used with `\specialrule` instead of `\hline`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42412/longtable-does-not-break-correctly-when-used-with-specialrule-instead-of-hline)

Here the author have faced the problem described above. He'd tried to use `\specialrule` from the `booktabs` package but the output at page break was buggy. The solution was to use normal `\hline` with previously adjusted `\arrayrulewidth`. Unfortunately, this can be applied only to the whole longtable, but not to the individual `\hline`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be lacking a question, as you just quote two answers, but an answer to a possibly related question is

```
 \\
 \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth0.5cm}
 \hline
 \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth0.4pt}
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way (taken from [here](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/thicker-hline-before-firsthead-of-longtable/1910637)):

```
\newcommand{\myhline}{\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth1cm}\hline
                      \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth1pt}}
```

or

```
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{0pt}
\newcommand{\myhline}{\hline\hline\hline}
```