# Problem with longtabu and tabucline on pagebreak

Tags: tabu

I've got a `tabu` package related question. In the `longtabu` environment using `\hline` works perfectly. But when I try to use `\tabucline[...]` instead, on `pagebreak` there is one line missing.

Info according my preamble which I think may be relevant:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,BCOR8mm,DIV=calc,oneside,headings=normal,parskip=half,toc=graduated,bibliography=totocnumbered,draft]{scrreprt}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{frutigernext}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=30mm, right=29mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,bindingoffset=8mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[markuppercase,clines]{scrpage2} 
\clearscrheadfoot
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}
\chead[]{}
\automark{chapter}
\ihead[\headmark]{\uppercase{\headmark}}
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\setheadsepline{0.5pt}

% ----- TABELLEN -----
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\ctabukopf}{\taburowcolors[1]1{gray!100 .. gray!100}\rowfont[c]\bfseries\hline}
...
```

Now using `\hline` in `longtabu`:

```
\scriptsize
\tabulinesep=0.8ex
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X[ml]X[ml]X[ml2.5]|}
\ctabukopf
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Programmaufrufe}\\ \hline
\taburowcolors[1]1{white .. white}              
\textbf{Aufruf} & \textbf{Argument} & \textbf{Bedeutung}\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
\end{longtabu}  
\tabureset
\normalsize
```

Result (OK): [http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/a.jpg http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/a.jpg](http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/a.jpg)

Using `\tabucline[...]` in `longtabu`:

```
\scriptsize
\tabulinesep=0.8ex
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {|X[ml]X[ml]X[ml2.5]|}
\ctabukopf
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Programmaufrufe}\\ \hline
\taburowcolors[1]1{white .. white}              
\textbf{Aufruf} & \textbf{Argument} & \textbf{Bedeutung}\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \tabucline[on 2pt gray!100]
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \tabucline[on 2pt gray!100]
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \tabucline[on 2pt gray!100]
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
Example1 & Example2 & Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example Little bit longer example\\ \hline
\end{longtabu}  
\tabureset
\normalsize
```

Result (crashed): [http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/b.jpg http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/b.jpg](http://homepages-nw.uni-r.de/~ocs23577/b.jpg)

Do you know how to address this problem correctly?
Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

The [tabu documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf) has the following note (v2.8, p. 9):

> `\tabucline` does not care of page breaks presently: use `\hline` instead.

So simply using `\hline` is indeed the recommended solution.

Of course, `\tabucline` has a bunch of features that `\hline` lacks, including style options that control thickness, colors, and dashing. If you're using any of these features, simply using `\hline` won't meet your needs. The ideal solution would be for tabu's author, or some other TeXnical wizard, to make `\tabucline` compatible with page breaks. In the meantime, however, I can show you some simple workarounds I've found that will allow you to control the **thickness** and **color** of ordinary `\hline`s while preserving the behavior you seek (repeating rules that occur on page breaks). In this way, you can get some of the most popular features that `\tabucline` provides (control over the thickness and color of individual rules) while preserving the good behavior across page breaks that `\hline` has. (Because they use only `\hline`, these techniques should work fine with any longtable; it needn't necessarily be a longtabu.)

First, the simple case: if you need to change the thickness and/or color of *all* rules in your table, this is quite easy to do. For thickness, set the `\arrayrulewidth` length, and for color, load the colortbl package and use the `\arrayrulecolor` command. That is, put

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}
```

right before the table and

```
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
```

right after the `\begin{longtabu}` declaration.

Things get harder if you want to control thickness and color on a per-rule basis—that is, if you want some horizontal rules in a table to be thick and black, while others are thin and blue. Fortunately, I found [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50453/bold-hlines-for-longtable) that has a couple of answers that solve the hardest part of this problem for us. Here's an example of how this can be used in practice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in,paperheight=8.5in,margin=.5in,footskip=.25in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\thickhline}[1]{\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth#1}\hline
    \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth#1}}

\newcommand{\coloredthickhline}[2]{
    \arrayrulecolor{#1}
    \thickhline{#2}
    \arrayrulecolor{black}
}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=4pt
\begin{longtabu}{XX[1.7]} \thickhline{3pt}
    \textbf{Base Potions} &
        These potions have no effect...
    \\\coloredthickhline{blue!35!lightgray}{.5pt}
    \leftskip=3ex Awkward Potion &
        This is the base for most potions...
    \\\coloredthickhline{blue!35!lightgray}{.5pt}
    % etc.
    \\\thickhline{3pt}
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see, the rules behave as you would want them to: the rule on which a page break occurs is repeated on the new page with the correct color and thickness. Of course, this isn't a perfect solution—there are still plenty of other things that a `\tabucline` can do that an `\hline` can't—but I think it will satisfy most people's needs.