# Altering only header \hline colors with longtabu and colortbl

Tags: longtable, tabu, colortbl

I'm trying to make a table with the following properties:

1. If the table is very long, the header should be repeated on each new page.
2. Each row should be separated by a line.
3. The line immediately after the header row should be black, whereas all the other lines should be gray.

To achieve this, I'm using the `longtabu` environment, together with `colortbl` to change the color of the lines between the rows. According to the `colortbl` documentation, `\arrayrulecolor{}` will change the color of any lines after the statement. As such, I figured the following would work as expected:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{ l l }
\arrayrulecolor{black} % Make the header line black.
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\hline
\endhead
\arrayrulecolor{light-gray} % Any other lines that come after the header are gray.
Foo & Bar \\
\hline
Foo & Bar \\
\hline
% ... More lines ...
Foo & Bar \\
\hline
Foo & Bar
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

However, despite the fact that the header is properly repeated, the `\arrayrulecolor{black}` line *isn't* - i.e., only the very first header line is black, while the rest are `light-gray`.

I tried Googling, but I can't seem to find a good example of how to do this. How can I achieve the table style I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to load `colortbl`, since you can replace `\arrayrulecolor` with the command `\taburulecolor` provided by `tabu`.

Having said that, it works if you replace all `\hline`s with `\tabucline{1-}`.

Remember that you can issue the command

```
\everyrow{\tabucline{1-}}
```

if you want every row followed by an horizontal line.

MWE (I've substituted `black` with `red` just for displaying purposes):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{ l l }
\taburulecolor{red} % Make the header line black.
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\tabucline{1-}
\endhead
\taburulecolor{light-gray} % Any other lines that come after the header are gray.
\everyrow{\tabucline{1-}}
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\
Foo & Bar \\

\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

Output (second page):

[image]

Comment: This works decently well, but if I switch to `\tabucline` then I lose the page-breaking functionality of `\hline` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118988/problem-with-longtabu-and-tabucline-on-pagebreak). I may end up doing this, but I'll leave this questions open for a little while to see if anyone has a solution that uses `\hline`.