# Avoiding bottomrule to go to next page

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, rules

Sometimes my longtable bottom rules end up in the following page. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42412/longtable-does-not-break-correctly-when-used-with-specialrule-instead-of-hline

Comment: Thanks for answering. That's a very complicated post, though. I've tried to understand -- I've read it three times already, but no clue yet.

Comment: The message basically is not to use `\bottomrule`.

Comment: Do you have an example? I have a few ideas (if you still want to use `\bottomrule`), but a working example would help me know if they're any good.